# How to pass results from raw SQL query to view in Symfony2

Tags: symfony

I have this code that uses a raw SQL query inside my controller:

```
        $sql1 = "SELECT completion_date FROM enviro_figures_upload GROUP BY YEAR(completion_date), MONTH(completion_date) DESC;";

        $activeDate = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getConnection()->prepare($sql1);
        $activeDate->execute();
        $activeDate->fetchAll();
```

This code then passes the data to the view which is then used in a drop down date picker. However, no results are passed to the view even though running that SQL query on the database returns the results I need. What am I missing in order to pass this data to the view?

Comment: Seems work fine to me. How do you pass the data to the view? BTW: you can just do `$this->get('database_connection')->fetchAll('...');`

Comment: Provide the relevant code how you are passing data to view ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $activeDate->execute();
>     $activeDate->fetchAll();
>     This code then passes the data to the view  ...

this code doesn't pass the data to view, you have to pass the data to view by array option in `render` method..

something like this:

```
$sql1 = "SELECT completion_date FROM enviro_figures_upload GROUP BY YEAR(completion_date), MONTH(completion_date) DESC;";

$activeDate = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getConnection()->prepare($sql1);
$activeDate->execute();

$result = $activeDate->fetchAll();

return $this->render('TEMPLATE_PATH', [
    'result' => $result
]);
```

Comment: Or just return array with data, and template name is equal to your action name.

Comment: Only if you are using the `@Template` annotation.

Comment: This is correct, and it was exactly what I was doing. The issue was down to a memory issue on my development server which was preventing the query to run correctly.